# How can I access `AnyHashable` types in `Any` in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, swift3

I'm using [`APAddressBook`](https://github.com/Alterplay/APAddressBook) to get the address book from the users phone. it generates the following object of users when I print the variable `serializedContacts`:

```
[[
    AnyHashable("name"): {
        compositeName = "Mary Jones";
        firstName = Mary;
        lastName = Jones;
    },
    AnyHashable("recordID"): 111, 
    AnyHashable("phones"): <__NSSingleObjectArrayI 0x17401c160>({
           number = "0411 111 111";
    })
], 
[
    AnyHashable("name"): {
        compositeName = "Jack Smith";
        firstName = Jack;
        lastName = Smith;
    }, 
    AnyHashable("recordID"): 112, 
    AnyHashable("phones"): <__NSSingleObjectArrayI 0x17401c190>({
        number = "0422 222 222";
    })
]]
```

I can access a single contact by simply printing `serializedContacts[0]`, although how can I access the finer details such as `compositeName` and `number`?

I tried `serializedContacts[0].name` and `serializedContacts[0].phones`, although receive the error.

> Value of type 'Any' has no member 'name'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also convert the property you're trying to access to AnyHashable before. In your case this is:

```
serializedContacts[0][AnyHashable("name")]
```